# Не появляется css картинка

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Только когда ставлю padding картинка появляется.

А так не работает:

```css
#header-truck {
  background: url('../img/header_truck.png') no-repeat center top fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="header-truck">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Вставить лучше тут исполняемый код, на панели инструментов называется фрагмент кода

Comment: Если не появляется что либо в браузере, можно открыть инструменты разработчика и посмотреть на размеры, например блока. Вам тут нужно прописать height и min-height.

Answer (score 2):

блочный элемент должен иметь хотя бы min-height. Обычно занимаемый контентом. А так по умолчанию ваша картинка имеет значения width:100%; height:0;